# Unable to install php7.2 or 7.3 on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu-20.10

I want to install php7.2 or php7.3 on ubuntu 20.10 but i get this error :

```
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done E: Unable to locate package php7.3 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3'
```

before i ran these commands

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3
```

Does ubuntu 20.10 supports php 7.3 or 7.2 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.10 is [no longer supported by Canonical](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-July/000270.html) (EOL July 2021), and thus no longer supported by deb.sury.org (which only contains packages for released versions). You should downgrade to the LTS version 20.04 of Ubuntu, as for 21.10 the package support is [still in discussion](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1662)

Comment: Ok so i upgraded to 21.04 and it solved my problem, thanks a lot Nico Haase